# Nested "Do Until" and "For" loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

I am trying to create a macro that takes the data in column B from Sheet1 to Sheet2 if the names in column A Sheet1 corresponds to the names in column A in Sheet2. The first part of the code works fine, but the second part which is the "Do Until" loop is the problem. With the code I currently have, the loop runs through the outer loop and inner loop for the first name in Column A, but then it does not go through the outer loop for the rest of the names in Column A. The code is below:

```
Sub PullNames()

Dim A As Range
Dim B As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim A2 As Range
Dim B2 As Range
Dim C2 As Range
Dim LastA As Long
Dim LastB As Long
Dim LastC As Long
Dim LastA2 As Long
Dim CheckName As String
Dim CheckName2 As String
Dim count As Long


LastA = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastB = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
LastC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
count = 2

Set A = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastA)
Set B = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & LastB)
Set C = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:c" & LastC)
Set A2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & count)
Set B2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & count)
Set C2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & count)

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
A2.Activate

    A.Copy Destination:=A2
    A2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    A2.Columns.AutoFit


Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

LastA2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until count > LastA
    CheckName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & count)
    Name = CheckName

        'creates a loop for the macro to go through the names on Sheet2
        If count < LastA2 Then
            CheckName2 = A2
            Name2 = CheckName2
                If Name = Name2 Then
                    B2 = B.Value
                End If

        count2 = count2 + 1
        End If

count = count + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: One thing i noticed, you should not use variables that can be mistaken as cell references, it can be confusing. I think your problem is `If count < LastA2 Then` it should be `count2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one loop. The place where your comment starts "create a loop" isn't a loop, it's an If statement. Here's how you might rewrite your code if I understand the logic correctly.

```
Sub PullNames()

    Dim A As Range
    Dim B As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim A2 As Range
    Dim B2 As Range
    Dim C2 As Range
    Dim LastA As Long
    Dim LastB As Long
    Dim LastC As Long
    Dim LastA2 As Long
    Dim CheckName As String
    Dim CheckName2 As String
    Dim count As Long, count2 As Long
    Dim Name_ As String
    Dim Name2 As String

    LastA = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastB = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    LastC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 2

    Set A = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastA)
    Set B = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & LastB)
    Set C = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:c" & LastC)
    Set A2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & count)
    Set B2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & count)
    Set C2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & count)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    A2.Activate

    A.Copy Destination:=A2
    A2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    A2.Columns.AutoFit

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    LastA2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Do Until count > LastA
        CheckName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & count)
        Name_ = CheckName

            'creates a loop for the macro to go through the names on Sheet2
            'If count < LastA2 Then
            count2 = 2
            Do While count2 <= LastA2
                CheckName2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & count2)
                Name2 = CheckName2
                    If Name_ = Name2 Then
                        'B2 = B.Value
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & count2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & count).Value
                    End If

                count2 = count2 + 1
            Loop
            'End If

    count = count + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

If there are duplicates (that you removed), this code will pull the last value it encounters, which you may not want. If, for instance, B is a number, you may want to add those numbers together in column B.

Here's how I would have written the code.

```
Public Sub PullNames2()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rNames As Range

    'Define the range that contains the names
    'copy that range to sheet2 and remove the dupes
    Set rNames = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    rNames.Copy Sheet2.Range("A2")
    With Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Loop through all the names
    For Each rCell In rNames.Cells
        'use the Find method to find the name on sheet2
        Set rFound = Nothing
        Set rFound = Sheet2.Columns(1).Find(rCell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

        'If you found the name, add the value in B to whatever is already there
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value + rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

A couple of notes:

- I use codenames of sheets. These are the names VBA knows and are not the tab names. You don't have to use them, it's just my preference.
- CurrentRegion is good if you don't have any gaps. If it doesn't work for your data, you can set rNames however you like to define ranges. You'll just need to use the same methodology for sheet2.
- You have to set rFound to Nothing every time because it will remember the last time it found something. That way you can check for Nothing - that's what rFound is if it can't find what it's looking for.

**Always** test code from the internet on a copy of your data. Particularly code that changes stuff.